# Cannot install Taichi Lang

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I used Python's package installer `pip` to install taichi lang:

`pip install --upgrade taichi`

But the following error occurred:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement taichi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for taichi
```

How can I install Taichi Lang without running into that error?

Comment: What is your python version?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because `taichi` only supports versions from:

```
Requires: Python >=3.6, <3.12
```

your Python does not fall in the required range.

Link to taichi: https://pypi.org/project/taichi/